# Activate script only if specified columns change

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

This thing changes the status of two different columns dependent on each others' values. I want it to only trigger the script when the changes are in these two columns. This spreadsheet will have about 30 people on it and I do not want it activating every time a cell is edited. Please take a look and be aware I'm a complete newbee who pieced this together by Googling.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var data = s.getDataRange().getValues();
  var data_len = data.length;

  var headers = s.getRange(1, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var edit_headers = headers[0].indexOf('Edit');
  var qc_headers = headers[0].indexOf('QC');

  for(var i=0; i<data_len; i++) {
    var edit = data[i][edit_headers];
    var qc = data[i][qc_headers];
    var edit_stat =  s.getRange(i+1,edit_headers +1);
    var qc_stat =  s.getRange(i+1,qc_headers +1);

//Statuses for QC and Edit that change each other
    var stat_1 = "Needs QC";
    var stat_2 = "Pass";
    var stat_3 = "Fail";
    var stat_4 = "Fail Fix in Process";
    var stat_5 = "Re-QC";

//Switch instead of elseif
    switch (edit + qc) //edit + qc stats generate cases below
{
      case stat_1: //Needs QC + ""
        qc_stat.setValue(stat_1); //qc = Needs QC
        break;

      case stat_1 + stat_2: //Needs QC + Pass
        edit_stat.setValue(stat_2); //edit = Pass
        break;  

      case stat_1 + stat_3: //Needs QC + Fail
        edit_stat.setValue(stat_3); //edit = Fail
        break;  

      case stat_4 + stat_3: //Fail Fix in Process + Fail
        qc_stat.setValue(stat_4); //qc = Fail Fix in Process
        break;  

      case stat_1 + stat_4: //Needs QC + Fail Fix in Process
        qc_stat.setValue(stat_5); //qc = Re-QC
        break;   

//Below are fail safes
      case stat_2 + stat_3: //Pass + Fail; just in case qc Passes a fail
        edit_stat.setValue(stat_3); //edit = Fail
        break; 
      case stat_3 + stat_2: //Fail + Pass; just in case qc Fails a Pass
        edit_stat.setValue(stat_2); //edit = Pass
        break; 
}
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build an if-statement that checks the columns being edited and return (exit) the script if that column does not match the columns that are allowed to trigger the script (in which case indexOf will return -1).. E.g: let's say you only want to allow column 3 and 6 to trigger the script then do somehting like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var allowedCols = [3, 6];
 if (allowedCols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) === -1) return;
 //rest of your code..
 ...
 }
```

EDIT: If you also want to exclude certain tabs (see question in comments), you can try:

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var allowedCols = [3, 6];
 var disallowedTabs = ['Sheet3', 'Sheet5'];
 if (allowedCols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) === -1 || disallowedTabs.indexOf(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() > -1) return;
 //rest of your code..
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm going to try it out. Seems like this can literally improve performance on anything that is onEdit.

Comment: Hello sir, thank you again for the previous code. I was wondering, is there also a way to disable the script on specific tabs that I name? Thanks!